# android cnfException

Tags: android, maps, classnotfoundexception

i'm trying to code an app that displays the current device position on a map. When i try to install it onto the device it says it cant find the class that is my main activity. it also says that dalvikvm can't resolve it the class' superclass, which is clearly MapActivity. Any ideas? thanks.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

public class WcFinderActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText        txted           = null;

    Button          btnSimple       = null;

    MapView         gMapView        = null;

    MapController   mc              = null;

    Drawable        defaultMarker   = null;

    GeoPoint        p               = null;

    double          latitude        = 18.9599990845, longitude = 72.819999694;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Creating TextBox displying Lat, Long
        txted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id1);
        String currentLocation = "Lat: " + latitude + " Lng: " + longitude;
        txted.setText(currentLocation);

        // Creating and initializing Map
        gMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myGMap);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000), (int) (longitude * 1000000));
        gMapView.setSatellite(true);
        mc = gMapView.getController();
        mc.setCenter(p);
        mc.setZoom(14);

        // Add a location mark
        MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay();
        List<Overlay> list = gMapView.getOverlays();
        list.add(myLocationOverlay);

        // Adding zoom controls to Map
        ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) gMapView.getZoomControls();
        zoomControls.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        gMapView.addView(zoomControls);
        gMapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        // Getting locationManager and reflecting changes over map if distance travel by
        // user is greater than 500m from current location.
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
    }

    /* This method is called when use position will get changed */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            String currentLocation = "Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng;
            txted.setText(currentLocation);
            p = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);
            mc.animateTo(p);
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    /* User can zoom in/out using keys provided on keypad */
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() + 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O) {
            gMapView.getController().setZoom(gMapView.getZoomLevel() - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            gMapView.setSatellite(true);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T) {
            gMapView.setTraffic(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Class overload draw method which actually plot a marker,text etc. on Map */
    protected class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
            Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);

            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
            canvas.drawText("I am here...", myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

01-18 15:04:07.223: W/dalvikvm(3554): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/tecmark/WcFinderActivity; (23)
    01-18 15:04:07.238: W/dalvikvm(3554): Link of class 'Lcom/tecmark/WcFinderActivity;' failed
    01-18 15:04:07.238: D/AndroidRuntime(3554): Shutting down VM
    01-18 15:04:07.238: W/dalvikvm(3554): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b180)
    01-18 15:04:07.238: E/AndroidRuntime(3554): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tecmark/com.tecmark.WcFinderActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tecmark.WcFinderActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43e57a18
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tecmark.WcFinderActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43e57a18
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
    01-18 15:04:07.278: E/AndroidRuntime(3554):     ... 11 more

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.tecmark"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

            <application
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".WcFinderActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

            </application>



        </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i made a silly mistake. i moved the uses-library tag inside the application tag and it compiles and installs on phone now. i think that explains the superclass can not be resloved error as well. my activity extends MapActivity, this is probably defined in the google api library that was not declared between the application tags.